# Offset cursor Y position NSTextField cocoa

Tags: cocoa, cursor, offset, nstextfield

I am using an NSTextField in a small area and the flashing cursor is not positioned where i want it, the text is in the right place but the cursor is too high (see image). Is there any way I can offset it so it appears lower?

Thanks in advance, Ben.

[image: Example]

**Edit:**
Heres my code for creating the text field:

```
text = [[TextField alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(38, 8, self.frame.size.width-97, self.frame.size.height-8)];
[text setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
[text setTextColor:[NSColor grayColor]];
[text setFocusRingType:1];
[text setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:14]];

[self addSubview:text];
```

And the subclass:

```
#import "TextField.h"

@implementation TextField

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.

    }

    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    // Drawing code here.
}

@end
```

Comment: Looks like a custom text field. If that's true, please post your code.

Comment: It is but so far all ive done is stop it drawing its background with setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor] and then placed it on top of an NSView with the custom background drawn into it.

Comment: @BenJacob We can't help you if we don't know how you're drawing the text field.

Comment: @TheAmateurProgrammer I have included all my code associated with the textfield.

Comment: Have you checked if the font used in your NSTextField installed? (almost sure that it is out of date. But... I'll try:) )